# Bootstrap 3 collapse panel isnt working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use the collapse-panel from bootstrap 3. So i copy the example from the w3schools example.

```
    <div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
      <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and thought this will work. But it doesnt. Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>test</title>

    <!--Einbinden von less und less-compiler -->
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.5/less/bootstrap.less">
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.5/js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/stickyfooter.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible panel</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see the panel and the header is linked. But nothing show up if i click it.

Iam new to Webdevelopment so i think its a noob problem. :D

Info: Bootstrap is loaded, i can use the css well. Jquery should be loaded too because i can use `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-3.3.5/less/bootstrap.less">
```

With this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

---

**REASON:**

**Less.js** browser script currently won’t work if you’re using Chrome and the path to your page starts with “file:///” due to a known Chrome issue.

Via- http://fadeyev.net/lessjs-will-obsolete-css/

Comment: it doesnt work either. Firefox isnt also working. :/